# entrypoint command in gitlabci image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Please explain what this entrypoint command does in gitlabci file

```
stages:
  - tfsec

    Terraform Security:
      allow_failure: true
      image:
        name: aquasec/tfsec
        entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

If it works in gitlabci, why does docker run fail with /bin/sh?

```
docker run --rm -it aquasec/tfsec /bin/sh       
Error: provided path is not a dir
```

Answer (score 0):

What is you gitlab version?
If it is greater than 17.06 , then use `entrypoint: [""]`

Comment: Thankyou for your response..Actually my question is different. I want to understand why entrypoint works in gitlabci but in docker run it fails for /bin/sh.

Comment: Well it looks like you have placed you entry point command in wrong position.
General docker command looks like `docker run -it --entrypoint <ENTRYPOINT COMMAND> image <CMD...>`.

In your command, you are using `/bin/sh` in place of CMD rather than ENTRYPOINT.
Change your command to `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint  /bin/sh   
 aquasec/tfsec`.